# Uploading traing video via Scorm package ,it only shows loading but doesnt play

Tags: moodle, scorm

I'm trying to add a training content on Moodle via scrom when I press save and display then click preview to see it playing it only shows loading it doesn't  play, what is it that I need to enable on Moodle in order for it to play, I have updated my flash player , I'm on I.E 11,moodle version 2.8 is there a plugin that I need to install?

Comment: If you open up the console in developer tools, do you see any errors?

Comment: Either your SCORM package is faulty, or that you're having Browser compatibility issues.

Does it work in Chrome?
If you look in your Developer tools, can you see the embed code?
If you look in the console, are you getting any fatal errors?

Comment: Consider the possibility the mime-types for the videos you're attempting to play might not be enabled.  Flash uses FLV, MP4, M4V from my memory so you may need to verify the server can serve these files.  You'd need to check the Multimedia Plugins Filter in administration or Managing filters.  I suspect this plays fine outside of moodle so I'd start there.